# collapse panel in view page is showing first record on all button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    <table class="table" >
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
                <tr>

                    <td>
                    <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails_@item.Title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </a>

                <div class="collapse" id="viewdetails_@item.Title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Budget)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EstimatedHours)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EstimatedHours)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SuggestedSources)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SuggestedSources)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProposedDeadline)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProposedDeadline)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

            </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                    </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

/* The above is my code. I want a collapse on title click. There are several titles, but on every title click the collapse window shows me first record. What should I do to show respective title record.*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are passing same id in for loop to the elements that is wrong, in your page everty anchor tag will have data-target **viewdetails** due to which it will always open the first div with **viewdetials** id which browser will find in the **DOM**

do like this:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails_@item.Id" onclick="">
```

and in div:

```
<div class="collapse" id="viewdetails_@item.Id">
```

or you can use **IndexOf** method of the list item and pass that with the ids:

and in div:

```
<div class="collapse" id="viewdetails_@Model.IndexOf(item)">
```

Comment: There is another problem now. It get collapse on button click and immediately get closed.

Comment: can you provide fiddle, so that it can be corrected easily

Comment: i have edited the code. Please check it. Check for first <td> inside foreach

Comment: If you can make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net